# What to do in case of concentric circles that are not aligned with the cross after collimation (Picture inside)?

Tags: telescope, collimation

I have been collimating my newly bought first Newtonian telescope for a few days now, but I can't get the center of the circles to align with the intersection point of the spider's reflection. I have drawn a simple picture that illustrates what I see:

[image]

My question is, which mirror do I need to adjust, and in which way, in order to get the cross to align with the circles in the correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
If this is something that is not supposed to happen, then please tell me so that I would contact the seller. Thanks again.

Comment: Spider reflection looks uncentered. That'd happen if main mirror is tilted.

Comment: The location of the spider does not matter. You want all of the optics aligned. Are the optics aligned? Is the spider a different design or is the spider physically centered in the tube?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger
Which mirror of the two?

Comment: @JohnHoltz
By all optics do you mean the circles?

Comment: @RamyGaw The main, big, mirror.

Comment: The image is not visible to me